# How to inherit mongoengine.django.auth.User for Custom User Model?

Tags: django, django-models, mongoengine, django-socialauth

I am pretty new with django. I am using django, mongoengine, django-social-auth to build authentication system and to store user profile in mongodb.

I am in process of using 'Custom User Model' mechanism provided by django as follows:

```
from mongoengine import *
from mongoengine.django.auth import User

class UserProfile(User):

    imageUrl = URLField()

    def __init__(self):
        User.__init__()
```

settings.py include ('users' is app name):

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'
```

When I execute 'python manage.py runserver', got following error:

```
social_auth.usersocialauth: 'user' has a relation with model users.UserProfile, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

When I change my UserProfile class to inherit from models.Model as follows:

```
from mongoengine import *
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    imageUrl = URLField()

    def __init__(self):
        User.__init__()
```

,running 'python manage.py runserver' started development server without an issue.

So I guess, Custom User Model must be inherited from models.Model. So how should I workaround to inherit my custom user model from mongoengine.django.auth.User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you just create a UserProfile with one-to-one relationship to build in User model from django. So this is not true:

```
 SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'
```

You should create your own User model. Follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

**Example:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45, db_index=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField()
    activation_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    login_at = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_fullname(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_shortname(self):
        return self.first_name

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```